# Hostapd ignoring Channel Configuration

Tags: bash, hostapd

I tried to setup a fake Access Point using hostapd but it turns out it keeps on ignoring the channel configuration in the hostapd.conf file.

**hostapd.conf**

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=*wifi ssid of other AP*
channel=*channel of other AP + 1*
```